# Template ressource ON JSF2

Tags: java, netbeans, war, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4

I have a problem with path of template in JSF2.
My template is in other war. I had this war on libraries.

But I don't found this template.

[Image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1nYB.png)

The target of this. It's a intranet with many applications war.
[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7PZ9.png)

Thanks

Manu

Comment: Thee image says everything. The template is just in the wrong location.

Comment: Thanks, it's possible to explain for the good location.